# how to use find_element after finding the hyperlink through click()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I used

```
continue_link=driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text("contract")
```

to get a list of links. How do I apply find_elements on web elements I got already?

And how to return strings on web pages? Can find_element do that?

For example:

```
      <div class="article-detail-text">
         <h1>notice</h1>
         <p class="article-date">release date：2019-05-22</p>

       <p>hi：<br />
　　I like basketball and football.<br />
　　I like cooking.<br />
　　Thanks.</p>
```

And I want to return:
"I like basketball and football. I like cooking. Thanks."

Comment: This is very unclear. Do you want to use `find_elements()` on the web elements in `continue_link` or do you want to go to the page of this link and use `find_elements()` there. What do you mean by *how to return string according to string indexes*? edit your question to include **one** clear question.

Comment: @Guy Thank you for noticing me. I have modified the question. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the correct [XPath expression](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) to match the HTML snippet you provided would be something like:

```
//div[@class='article-detail-text']/descendant::p[contains(text(),'hi')]
```

Once you locate the relevant [`<div>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp) you will be able to get the text of the [descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/descendant) [`<p>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp) using [innerText property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

```
print(driver
      .find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='article-detail-text']/descendant::p[contains(text(),'hi')]")
      .get_attribute("innerText"))
```

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`WebElement` has `find_elements()` functions as well

```
continue_link = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text("contract")
for link in continue_link:
    elements = link.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('')
```

And to get specific substring you can do

```
s1 = 'I like basketball and football'
s2 = 'like'

result = s1[s1.index(s2) + len(s2):]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It solves my first question. I edited my second question again. And I think it is very clear this time.

Answer (score 0):

To return the text `I like basketball and football. I like cooking. Thanks.` You can try the following option.

```
print(' '.join(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[contains(.,'hi:')]").text.split('hi:')[1].splitlines()))
```

This will print :

```
I like basketball and football. I like cooking. Thanks.
```